# Creating Rank in SAS

Tags: sas, rank

I have this data in SAS:

| id | year_mont | sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 202201 | 85.28 |
| 1 | 202202 | 90.05 |
| 1 | 202203 | 85.28 |
| 1 | 0 | 85.28 |
| 1 | 202205 | 85.28 |
| 1 | 202206 | 85.28 |
| 1 | 202207 | 85.28 |

I need to create a rank that increases after zero and decreases before zero, per id, like that:

| id | year_mont | sales | rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 202201 | 85.28 | -3 |
| 1 | 202202 | 90.05 | -2 |
| 1 | 202203 | 85.28 | -1 |
| 1 | 0 | 85.28 | 0 |
| 1 | 202205 | 85.28 | 1 |
| 1 | 202206 | 85.28 | 2 |
| 1 | 202207 | 85.28 | 3 |

Is it possible to do it in SAS?

Answer (score 1):

You need to know how many observations there are in the group and which one is the zero.

You can use a double DOW loop.  The first loop to count the observations and find where the zero is.  The second one to generate RANK variable and re-read the data so it can be written out.

```
data have;
  input id year_month sales;
cards;
1 202201 85.28
1 202202 90.05
1 202203 85.28
1      0 85.28
1 202205 85.28
1 202206 85.28
1 202207 85.28
;

data want ;
  found=0;
  do nobs=1 by 1 until(last.id);
    set have;
    by id;
    if year_month=0 then found=nobs;
  end;
  do rank=1-found to nobs-found ;
    set have;
    output;
  end;
run;
```

Results:

```
                               year_
Obs    found    nobs    id     month    sales    rank

 1       4        7      1    202201    85.28     -3
 2       4        7      1    202202    90.05     -2
 3       4        7      1    202203    85.28     -1
 4       4        7      1         0    85.28      0
 5       4        7      1    202205    85.28      1
 6       4        7      1    202206    85.28      2
 7       4        7      1    202207    85.28      3
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but didn't work when the last year_month is the zero value.

Comment: Fixed. The old formula only worked when NOBS was 1+2*FOUND.  What do you want when no zero is found?  The current code will number from from 1 to NOBS.

Comment: ., In the example above, if the zero were at 202207, the rank would be -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0.

Comment: Yes. 1-7 is -6,  7-7 is 0.

Comment: When I put to running in a large dataset the result didn't was the expected.

Comment: Make a small example that recreates the issues you see.  For example is it possible to have multiple zeros for the same ID?  What do you want to do then?